# Ansible: mapping network drive issues

Tags: powershell, ansible, mapping, network-drive

After performing `Ansible` playbook with task responsible for mapping network drive (I didn't use the `win_mapped_drive` module, used `powershell` commands) with a result `Successful` , mapped drive is not visible after RDP to the PC client where it was performed.

1. `Ansible` playbook task below. `Vars` are defined in a client specific `.yml` file and were substituted correctly.

```
-
  name: Step 9 Map a network drive with new credentials - tag share_mod
  win_shell: $driveLetter = "T" ; $networkPath = "{{ fs_path }}" ; $username = "{{ fs_acc }}" ; $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "{{ fs_acc_pwd }}" -AsPlainText -Force ; $credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePassword ; New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $networkPath -Credential $credential  -Persist
  tags:
    - share_add
```

2. After RDP to this PC Client, there is no mapped drive with a letter `T`
   [Vie from File Explrer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5a0Y.png)
3. Output from `Powershell` non-admin
   [powershell non-admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3KQr.png)
4. Output from `Powershell` as admin
   [powershell admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GULG3.png)
   There the `Local Path Z:` is displayed because of the drive mapped manually on the same PC Client but on a different user profile.

Comment: This may be related to UAC, where mapped drives in different 'context' are not visible by default for security reasons.  Changing the [EnableLinkedConnections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command) registry setting might help.

Comment: thanks, I've check EnableLinkedConnections registry settings and it's all configured as it supposted to be. I've looked also for the workarounds, and I think both won't apply.